# Android: how to lose focus on editText when testing with espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I want to test my error message in my android app. My error check only happens when the focus of my editText changes.

```
@Test
    fun wrongFirstname(){
        onView(withId(R.id.txtFirstNameRegister)).perform(typeText(""))
        //here I need to lose my focus
        onView(withId(R.id.txtFirstNameRegister)).check(matches(hasErrorText(R.string.firstNameCheckError.toString())))
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I know there is no explicit method that allows you to just lose focus, this is also not an action a user can perform hence it is not included in espresso.

You can of course use a different method resulting in loss of focus such as clicking on a different component:

```
onView(withId(R.id.some_view)).perform(click())
```

Comment: Clicking on a different view doesn't change the focus unless `some_view` is something that can take the focus like an `EditText`. Great solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `ViewAction` similar to existing `click()` or `clearText()` that executes `View::clearText` method over your `EditText`:

```kotlin
fun clearFocus(): ViewAction = object : ViewAction {
    override fun getDescription(): String = "clear focus"

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> =
        AllOf.allOf(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(), ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(EditText::class.java))

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
        view?.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

And then use it like any other action:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edit_text_about_to_lose_focus)).perform(clearFocus())
```